# calling c++ function from Java using swig in Windows, getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface, swig

I have this c++ code:

```
/* File : example.cpp */
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

double My_variable = 3.0;

int fact(int n) {
if (n <= 1) return 1;
else return n*fact(n-1);
}

int my_mod(int x, int y) {
return (x%y);
}

char *get_time()
{
time_t ltime;
time(&ltime);
return ctime(&ltime);
}
```

and I have this .i code:

```
/* example.i */
%module example
%{
/* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
extern double My_variable;
extern int fact(int n);
extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
extern char *get_time();
%}

extern double My_variable;
extern int fact(int n);
extern int my_mod(int x, int y);
extern char *get_time();
```

I am trying to call these functions from inside java. So in windows 7 (with mingw) cmd I do:

```
swig -c++ -java example.i
g++ -c example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\include" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\include\win32"
g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.dll -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\include" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\include\win32"
```

This creates a dll file. Now I try to run the following java program:

```
public class main {
   public static void main(String argv[]) {
     System.loadLibrary("example");
     System.out.println(example.fact(5));
     System.out.println(example.get_time());
   }
 }
```

So I run

```
javac main.java
```

It compiles fine, but when I run using

```
java main
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:     exampleJNI.fact(I)I
        at exampleJNI.fact(Native Method)
        at example.fact(example.java:20)
        at main.main(main.java:4)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You need to call java with -Djava.library.path=<the/path/containing/example.dll>.  See: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response, but it doesn't work that way. I get the same error. actually java finds and loads the dll but I don't know what goes wrong after that. If java couldn't find the dll, it would give me something like this:       

    " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no example in java.li
brary.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at main.main(main.java:3) "

Comment: the other option is that your DLL cant find something it depends on.... checkout depends 2.2 for windows.  It will tell you if some dependency isn't found.

Comment: It looks like you call to `loadLibrary` worked fine and the compiler invocation looks good (in principle). I suspect that the problem comes from the C++ compiler - does it work if you do a pure C implementation and call gcc instead of g++?

Comment: Actually looks like it's a linker error, see http://www.mingw.org/node/41 but basically you probably need to add `-Wl,--kill-at` to the command line when you link. (I'll write this up and explain it as a proper answer if it works)

Comment: Hi Flexo, Actually it worked with the command -Wl,--kill-at. Would you please explain it for me? I would really appreciate that. thanks

Comment: @Bob can you show the full command you used ? I am having this issue also

Comment: I am using 
    `g++ -c example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -static -Wl,--kill-at`
and
    `g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o  -o example.dll  -static -Wl,--kill-at`

Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @Bob I am using windows. So I tried doing this g++ -c example.cpp example_wrap.cxx -static -Wl,--kill-at -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\include\win32" and then this g++ -shared example.o example_wrap.o -o example.dll -static -Wl,--kill-at but it's still not working

Comment: @Bob I figured it out. I did this first swig -c++ -Wall -java example.i

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using

```
-Wl,--kill-at
```

Thanks for comments.